# Django .update doesn't call override save?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to call this overrride save method in models:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.done is True:
        if self.averagepa is None:
            pass
        elif self.averagepa < 26:
            self.links = 5
        elif self.averagepa < 31:
            self.links = 10
        elif self.averagepa < 36:
            self.links = 15
        elif self.averagepa < 41:
            self.links = 20
        else:
            self.links = 99
super(KW, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This works perfectly if I just save model in admin panel. But when I try to update it via `./manage.py shell` like this:

```
KW.objects.filter(id=138).update()
```

It doesn't trigger it. How can I call save override method with update from shell?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the [documented behaviour](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) of the `update()` method.

> Be aware that the `update()` method is converted directly to an SQL statement. It is a bulk operation for direct updates. It doesn’t run any `save()` methods on your models, or emit the pre_save or post_save signals (which are a consequence of calling `save()`), or honor the auto_now field option. If you want to save every item in a QuerySet and make sure that the `save()` method is called on each instance, you don’t need any special function to handle that. Just loop over them and call `save()`.

In your case:

```
kw = KW.objects.get(id=138)
# update kw
kw.save()
```

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi either change your code to use `save()` as above, or update the field yourself, e.g. `queryset.update(updated_at=timezone.now(), ...)`

Comment: But looping over multiple objects inorder to use save() will have performance disadvantages over queryset.update. Due to the number of queries

Comment: If performance is an issue in your case then update the field yourself.